# Why does this variable return undefined instead of an object in my Angular 13 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

I am working on an e-commerce app who's front-end is made in Angular 13.

I use a service to handle the products coming from an API. I run into a problem while ring to display the *product details*.

See **Stackblitz** demo **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqr8ns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**.

In `app\services\product.service.ts` I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product, ProductResponse } from '../models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  products: Product[] = [];

  apiURL: string = 'https://dummyjson.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  // Product List       
  public getProducts(): Observable<ProductResponse>{
    return this.http.get<ProductResponse>(`${this.apiURL}/products`);
  }

  // Product Details (single product)
  public getProductDetails(id: Number): Observable<ProductResponse>{
    return this.http.get<ProductResponse>(`${this.apiURL}/products/${id}`);
  }
}
```

In `app\app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { ProductItemComponent } from './components/product-item/product-item.component';
import { ProductsListComponent } from './components/products-list/products-list.component';
import { ProductsDetailsComponent } from './components/products-details/products-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:  HomeComponent},
  { path: 'products', component:  ProductsListComponent},
  { path: 'products/show/:id', component:  ProductsDetailsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    ProductsListComponent,
    ProductItemComponent ,
    ProductsDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In `app\models\product.ts`:

```
export class Product {
    id?: number;
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    price?: number;
    discountPercentage?: number;
    rating?: number;
    stock?: number;
    brand?: string;
    category?: string;
    thumbnail?: string;
}

export interface ProductResponse {
    products: Product[];
    total: number;
    skip: number;
    limit: number;
}
```

In `app\components\products-details\products-details.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, InputDecorator, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Product, ProductResponse } from '../../models/product';
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-details',
  templateUrl: './products-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductsDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product!: Product;
  productResponse: any;

  constructor(private ProductService: ProductService, private Router: Router, private ActivatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.ProductService.getProductDetails(id).subscribe((response) => (this.productResponse = response));

  }
}
```

In `app\components\products-details\products-details.component.html` I have:

```
<h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
```

#### The problem

When I access a product details route (for instance, `http://localhost:4200/products/show/1`), the page displays an empty `<h1>` tag and the Chrome console shows `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`.

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning `product` there... you have it as a field decorated with an `@Input()` decorator, however, you assign `productResponse` instead and do all the processing in the component itself, instead of receiving it as an input?

Comment: @Jcl I have replaced `productResponse: any` with `@Input() productResponse!: ProductResponse` but the problem persists.

Comment: what in my comment suggested you to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the `https://dummyjson.com/products` endpoint, the `https://dummyjson.com/products/{id}` returns a plain `Product` object, so:

```js
// product.service.ts
public getProductDetails(id: Number): Observable<Product>{
  return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.apiURL}/products/${id}`);
}

// products-details.component.ts
// the @Input decorator is wrong — the data is not passed to the component from outside
// but instead fetched inside of the component
@Input() product!: Product;
// productResponse: any — this field is unused and should be removed

ngOnInit(): void {
  ...
  this.ProductService.getProductDetails(id).subscribe((product) => (this.product = product));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `@Input()` property only works for external assignment of values.

The following will probably do what you want:

```
product: Product | undefined;
```

```
this.ProductService.getProductDetails(id).subscribe((response) => (this.product = response));
```

```
<h1>{{ product?.title }}</h1>
```

Furthermore I believe handling raw responses should happen in the service instead of the component, but that may be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I get an error: `Type 'ProductResponse' has no properties in common with type 'Product'.`

Comment: Why does getting the details of a single product return a `ProductResponse` object that contains multiple/paged products?